# PNG logo image with rough edges

Tags: images, png

I made a logo by taking a screenshot and saving it as a .PNG file.  The edges on the logo are not as smooth as, say, the Google logo on Google.com.

How can I make the edges smooth?

Comment: It's best to start from scratch when creating logos. Screenshots are *always* low resolution. In addition, what exactly are you taking a screenshot of? The art must exist somewhere... if you don't have/own the original art, then you can't very well use someone else's art as a "logo".

Answer (score 2):

In fact, as @Scott said, if you don't have a logo in a vectorial format (or some raw format) it's better to start one from scratch.

As a helping tip, I'd recommend you to use *Illustrator* to be able to make it in vectorial format so as you can scale it without problems. And, if you let me, I'd use the ***"Pixel perfect"*** method, with the option ***"Snap to pixel grid"*** from *Illustrator*.

With this, you won't have problems of scalling and antialiasing and you'll end up with a clear and crispy image (in most cases), because there are not middle pixels.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's a formal construction :P this way they think they are making the choice when, in fact, they are following mine!

Answer (score 0):

Create logo with smooth edge and use "Save for Web" from photoshop and select PNG Export...